# What is the opposite of @login_required decorator for Django views?

Tags: django, django-authentication

If I want to make sure that a view is listed as having public access, is there a decorator equivalent to @public_access which would be the opposite of @login_required and make it clear that the view should be publicly accessible always?

One use case I have in mind is to automatically add "@csrf_exempt" to all public views in addition to making it clear in the code that the view should be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no built-in support for this in Django, leaving you at risk of exposing sensitive info when `@login_required` is accidentally forgotten.

Here's a solution from one of my projects:

`middleware/security.py`:

```
def public(function):
    """
    Decorator for public views that do not require authentication
    """
    orig_func = function
    while isinstance(orig_func, partial):  # if partial - use original function for authorization
        orig_func = orig_func.func
    orig_func.is_public_view = True
    
    return function

def is_public(function):
    try:                                    # cache is found
        return function.is_public_view
    except AttributeError:                  # cache is not found
        result = function.__module__.startswith('django.') and not function.__module__.startswith('django.views.generic') # Avoid modifying admin and other built-in views
        
        try:                                # try to recreate cache
            function.is_public_view = result
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        
        return result


class NonpublicMiddleware(object):

    def process_view_check_logged(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        return
    
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        while isinstance(view_func, partial):  # if partial - use original function for authorization
            view_func = view_func.func

        request.public = is_public(view_func)
        if not is_public(view_func):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():     # only extended checks are needed
                return self.process_view_check_logged(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)

            return self.redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())  # => login page

    def redirect_to_login(self, original_target, login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("%s?%s=%s" % (login_url, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, urlquote(original_target)))
```

`settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #...
    'middleware.security.NonpublicProfilefullMiddleware',
    #...
)
```

and, finally, view code:

```
from <projname>.middleware import publi

@public
def some_view(request):
    #...
    
# Login required is added automatically
def some_private_view(request):
    #...
```

Also, you may want to look at ["Automatically decorating all views of a django project"](http://blog.canb.net/2010/01/05/automatically-decorating-all-views-of-a-django-project/) blog post

Comment: I think it is also useful in some cases to *restrict* access to certain functionality if a user is logged in.  For example, don't allow a logged-in user to complete a registration form...  In this case you can use a combination of is_authenticated and is_anonymous:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authorization-for-anonymous-users

Answer (score 7):

As a previous poster mentioned, login not required is the default.

However, sometimes it's useful to block certain views from logged in users -- for instance, it makes no sense for a logged-in user to be able to use the site's signup page.  In that case, you could do something like this, based off the existing login_required decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.conf import settings

LOGGED_IN_HOME = settings.LOGGED_IN_HOME

def login_forbidden(function=None, redirect_field_name=None, redirect_to=LOGGED_IN_HOME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is NOT logged in, redirecting
    to the homepage if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: not u.is_authenticated(),
        login_url=redirect_to,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Comment: Use "u.is_anonymous()" insted of  "not u.is_authenticated()". See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser for more informations.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but another simple way to tackle this issue would be to rely on another decorator and add a lambda function:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_anonymous)
```

Comment: What the heck: "edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" Hell no! There is only missing brackets in `u.is_anonymous` so example is incorrect.

Comment: The example is correct and works. Where did you want to put additional brackets?

Comment: Oh, I've checked the docs. You are right, it's correct, since django 1.10+ `is_anonymous` became an attribute. But for previous versions of Django it'll give you always `True`, because `is_anonymous` was method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use user_passes_test and add a requirement, anonymous_required. This would work like the opposite to login_required and you can use on your register and login page - it is a bit irritating for users to still see the login page, after the are logged in.
This is how you would do it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

#Anonymous required 
def anonymous_required(function=None, redirect_url=None):

   if not redirect_url:
       redirect_url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

   actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
       lambda u: u.is_anonymous,
       login_url=redirect_url
   )

   if function:
       return actual_decorator(function)
   return actual_decorator


#Application of the Decorator

@anonymous_required
def register(request):
    #Your code goes here
```

Comment: Where I should put this? I mean, What file is recommended? Models, a new file in a specific structure?

Answer (score 0):

"Login not required" is the default. If you want to annotate that a view should never be login-restricted then you should do so in the docstring.

Answer (score 0):

I use [django-decorator-include](https://pypi.org/project/django-decorator-include/) to use the `login_required` decorator to secure an entire app, rather than one view at a time. My app's main urls.py looks like this:

```
path('my_secret_app/', decorator_include(login_required, ('my_secret_app.urls', 'my_secret_app'))),
```

This works great, except for when one of my apps has one view which needs to be public.

To get around this, I wrote my own `login_required` and `login_not_required`. My `login_required` is based on django's `django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required`, but is slightly modified to actually care when a view is marked as not requiring login.

My project is called `mysite`.

My app is called `my_secret_app`.

My public view within `my_secret_app` is called `MyPublicView`.

My entire solution looks like this:

mysite/lib.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

# A copy of django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required that looks for login_not_required attr
def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )

    if function:
        login_req = getattr(function, "login_required", True)

        if login_req:
            return actual_decorator(function)
        else:
            return function
    else:
        return actual_decorator

# Decorator to mark a view as not requiring login to access
def login_not_required(f):
    f.login_required = False
    return f
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from .lib import login_required
path('my_secret_app/', decorator_include(login_required, ('my_secret_app.urls', 'my_secret_app'))),
```

my_secret_app/views.py:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from mysite.lib import login_not_required

class MyPublicView(View):
    @method_decorator(login_not_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

You should be able to do the same thing no matter if you're subclassing `View`, `ListView`, `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, `TemplateView`, or any of the other ones. It should also work if you're using a function as your view, though I haven't tried it:

```
@login_not_required
def MyPublicView(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

@permission_classes([permissions.AllowAny])

Comment: No explanation of any kind - just code. I went digging for how to import permission_classes, and it appears to be part of rest_framework, which I'm not using. Either I'm wrong, and a few words about where to import it from, and where to add this code would have helped, or I'm right, and this is only relevant in cases where someone is using the rest framework, which there is no mention of anywhere in the original question