# django expose api that doesn't require authentication?

Tags: django

I have `django.contrib.auth` in my middleware, and I'd like to expose an API that doesn't require authentication.  How is that done?

```
class MY_API(APIView):
    #I'd like to let anonymous users call this post method...
    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254311/what-is-the-opposite-of-login-required-decorator-for-django-views