# Redirecting if already logged in

Tags: django

After my users log in, they can still access the login.html page and "log in again".  They can also manually access the pages meant to be seen only when registering ("enter your name and telephone number" sort of pages).  I'd rather they not be able to access these after they're logged in.

There is no `@login_forbidden` decorator.  So how can I redirect if a user is already logged in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the opposite of @login\_required decorator for Django views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254311/what-is-the-opposite-of-login-required-decorator-for-django-views)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - read the question you've linked please.  It is asking for something different (a public_access decorator)

Comment: no, if you move down the answers, you will see an answer that fits. For example [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798954/67579) one. `@public_access` as in *all* requests enabled makes no sense, since all views are publicly accessible by default.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - then that would make it not a duplicate question, but a question somewhat related that has an answer that happens to possibly fit this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view add this in first 2 line

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('app:index')
```